Connect to Digital Ocean Managed Database (Postgres) With NodeJS app
I have spent three days trying to connect to my DO Managed Database (Postgres version 16). My server is Ubuntu 22.04, and the NodeJS version is 20.18.0. I was connected to the database up until June 2023, but I think the SSL requirements changed at around that time, and my application hasn't been executing queries since then. That database was logging data that would be interesting for study, but it wasn't crucial to the operation of the business.
My code is
var promise = require('bluebird');
var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);

var cn2 = {
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST_MANAGED,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT_MANAGED,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE_DASHBOARD,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER_MANAGED,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD_MANAGED,
  ssl: {
   ca: '/path_to_cert/ca-certificate.crt',
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  }
};

const dshboard = pgp(cn2);

async function insertData() {
  console.log('in insertData');
  const query = 'INSERT INTO restarts (ts) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING ts';
  console.log('defined query');
  try {
    const result = await dshboard.one(query);
    console.log("printing right after running insert query");
    console.log('Inserted value:', result.ts); // Access returned column value
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing insert query:', error);
  }
}

insertData();


When insertData is called, "in insertData" is printed along with "defined query", but nothing in the try/catch is printed. The connection seems to fail, and anything related to queries on that connection are ignored. I believe all environment variables are correct, and the path to the location of the cert is correct. Further, I downloaded the cert two days ago and put it on that server, so the cert isn't old or anything.
